# How to add local OSM tile server to Geonode

Tags: openstreetmap, ubuntu, geonode

I have created 2 virtual machines each containing an installation of Geonode and an OSM Tile Server respectively. I would like to add the local OSM Tile Server to Geonode by following the [tutorial](http://docs.geonode.org/en/latest/tutorials/admin/production.html#adding-layers-from-google-bing-and-other-providers) however it does not provide anything regarding to locally hosted providers.

The tutorial gives only directions to Bing and Google Maps additions but not offline tile servers. The directions requires the need of an API key but my tile server does not provide one. I succesfully installed the OSM tile server via switch2OSM package into a Ubuntu 12.04 virtual machine. I was able to access the tile server via the host and separate virtual machine. I thought that I would just include the URL of my tile server to the Geonode instance to add it as one of my base maps but I can't seem to find where I should put it in?

Comment: Can you describe what you mean by "does not provide anything"? What do you see, what do you not see, and what were you expecting instead? Exactly what configuration did you put in? Does it work on the OSM VM? Does it work from a client machine direct to the OSM server?

Comment: Thank you for your response.
-*Can you describe what you mean by "does not provide anything"?* 
The tutorial gives only directions to Bing and Google Maps additions but not offline tile servers
-*What do you see, what do you not see, and what were you expecting instead?*
The directions requires the need of an API key but my tile server does not provide one
-*Exactly what configuration did you put in? Does it work on the OSM VM?*
I succesfully installed the OSM tile server via switch2OSM package into a Ubuntu 12.04 virtual machine.

Comment: -*Does it work from a client machine direct to the OSM server?*
Yes, it works. I was able to access the tile server via the host and separate virtual machine.

I thought that I would just include the URL of my tile server to the Geonode instance to add it as one of my base maps but I can't seem to find where I should put it in? Again thank you for your help.

Comment: You might like to put this key information in the question (just click edit below the question), especially the part about "Exactly what configuration did you put in?"...